# problem after selecting image using pen tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

Am using Photoshop to make this following effect

[image]
**and i have tutorial in PDF of above effect**

### And followed as given in step 2

[image]

After selecting after selecting specific part in image i need to go to **select>modify>feather**

but this is how i get when i selected my object
[image]

as you see in image the select option is inactive can someone help how to select ?? am new to Photoshop

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have a path, and no selection.

With the pen tool selected, right-click on the path and select "make selection".

Now you can choose modify-feather.

Comment: it works how do i remove background

Comment: Add a layer mask. Unlock the background first. Better is to make a duplicate of the background before you start editing.

Answer (score -1):

Select the image with pen and (cltr+enter) then go the path give value(0.5) and go do the Top of the(Selection bar) modify and Give contract and expand value(2).So that your selection all so click perfectly and now your picture will selcet perfectly.